# Extending in SKSpriteNode in swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, sprite-kit, extends, skspritenode

Basically this is very simple. I want to extend SKSpriteNode with just one variable.   I want it to be a variable number 1 through 8 that i can check against another global var.   The problem is, when I do an extension of SKSpriteNode and make a var like thisColor, it says that "extensions may not store properties"   Can anyone help me solve this problem???

Thanks!

Comment: why not use a subclass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is kind of telling you all that you need to know.

The only properties that extensions support [are those that are computed](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151). Which is essentially the same as using a function.

There's no way around this.

For example:

```
extension SKSpriteNode {

    var randomNumber: Int { return Int(arc4random_uniform(10)) }

}
```

Comment: How would i do that?  I want a number that in my main class I can randomly change using the arc4random_uniform!

Comment: So you want a random number generator added to SKSpriteNode?